# Spring Integration & Caching - How to add objects into cache from outbound-gateway reply-channel?

Tags: spring, caching, spring-integration, ehcache

I'm new to spring integration and caching and wanted to figure out how to add object that I received from outbound-gateway into cache. Unable to figure out the configurations which are required.

From following configuration, object that I received from rest api is getting logged:

INFO: com.domain.IpAddress@74589991

I'm planning to use ehcache/caffiene, any pointers will be helpful.

```
<int:channel id="requestChannel"/>
<int:channel id="outboundChannel"/> 
<int:channel id="replyChannel"/>
<int:channel id="autoCompleteJsonResponseChannel"/>

<int:gateway id="restResponseService" default-request-channel="requestChannel" service-interface="com.domain.service.RestResponseService" />

<int-http:outbound-gateway id="out" request-channel="requestChannel"
    http-method="GET"
    url="https://api.ipify.org/?format=json"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"   
reply-channel="autoCompleteJsonResponseChannel"
/>

<int:json-to-object-transformer
input-channel="autoCompleteJsonResponseChannel"
type="com.domain.IpAddress"
output-channel="outboundChannel" /> 

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="outboundChannel" level="INFO"/>
```

Edit 2:

Now I changed the outbound gateway as suggested:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway id="out" request-channel="requestChannel"
    http-method="GET"
    url="https://api.ipify.org/?format=json"
    expected-response-type="java.lang.String"
    reply-channel="autoCompleteJsonResponseChannel">
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
       <cache:advice>
           <cache:caching cache="myCache">
               <cache:cacheable method="getCurrentIpAddress" />
           </cache:caching>
       </cache:advice>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

and defined the ehcache configuration as follows:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheCacheManager" >
        <property name="cacheManager" ref="ehcache" />
    </bean>
    <!-- Ehcache library setup -->
    <bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean" >
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml" />
        <property name="shared" value="true"/>      
    </bean>
```

In my service class, defined the cacheable methods:

```
package com.domain.service;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.Cacheable;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.domain.IpAddress;
import com.domain.RestResponse;

@Service("restResponseService")
public class RestResponseServiceImpl implements RestResponseService{

    @Autowired
    private IpAddress ipAddress;
    @Cacheable("myCache")
    public IpAddress getCurrentIpAddress(String name) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return ipAddress;
    }

    @CacheEvict(value = "myCache", allEntries = true)
    public void refreshAllResults() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }
}
```

But still caching is not working. What I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this in your gateway:

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway>
    <int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <cache:advice>
                <cache:caching cache="foo">
                    <cache:cacheable method="handle*Message" key="#a0.payload"/>
                </cache:caching>
            </cache:advice>
    </int-http:request-handler-advice-chain>
</int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

In other words, since Caching in Spring in fully based on the AOP, it isn't so complicated to figure out that `request-handler-advice-chain` can use any `Advice` implementation. In this case we make `<cache:cacheable>` advice to work for us via proper method selection and caching key as an incoming payload.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Still have to get my AOP fundamentals to be right. one more query if I'll add it to outbound gateway it will cache the json response so I've to add it to my transformer(json-to-object-transformer) or to outboundChannel?

Comment: Don't understand your question. You add it into outbound gateway and it will cache a response, so the next request with the same key will read a cache and will be send to the outbound channel of that gateway

Comment: Thanks for the reply Artem. I'm trying with the configuration suggested by you but somehow caching is still not working. Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Could you please check the edit2 in question?

Comment: Explain, please, how your `@Cacheable` relates to the `<int-http:outbound-gateway>`. In general that `<cache:advice>` should not let to call external service for the same payload because of cache entry from the previous call.

Comment: sorry, updated with right configuration. Using same method, getCurrentIpAddress in <cache:advice> as well. From outbound channel, response is going to transformer   (<int:json-to-object-transformer
 input-channel="autoCompleteJsonResponseChannel"
 type="com.domain.IpAddress"
 output-channel="outboundChannel" />). Then I'm logging this response, (<int:logging-channel-adapter id="outboundChannel" level="INFO"/>). Problem is that if I'm trying to call same gateway twice, execution is getting hanged after the first call. i.e. object is getting logged only single time(never logging second time).

Comment: Still unclear how IP address is related to the http response.  Please, read more about caching. I've shown you how to cache http response. Your code with annotations is related